# Get value of dom element in ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my textArea to resize when the page is fully loaded. I found that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

can help me, so I try to test it and put next code into that function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = $('#elementId');
      alert(element.value);
});
```

But when the page is loading, alert shows **undefined** value of textArea, however there is text inside it.
How can I fetch those value inside ready function?

Comment: `$()` returns a jQuery object so you need to execute jQuery methods on it to get to the value, ie: `element.val()` or get the underlying reference to the DOM element and use `element[0].value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element` isn't a DOM element but a jQuery wrapped object, it doesn't have any `value` property.

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = $('#elementId');
      alert(element.val());
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = document.getElementById('elementId');
      alert(element.value);
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = $('#elementId');
      alert(element.get(0).value);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = $('#elementId');
      alert(element.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DOM object to use value property and you have jQuery object you need to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var element = $('#elementId');
      alert(element[0].value);
      //or  
      alert(element.val());           
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `alert(element.val());` instead of `alert(element[0].val());` in your second example?